# ruby version is latest but still getting error while installing rack and passenger, How to fix this?

Tags: ruby, centos7, passenger, rack

On centos-7

```
sudo gem install rack passenger

[root@puppetmaster bin]# sudo gem install rack passenger
ERROR:  Error installing rack:
        rack requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0.
ERROR:  Error installing passenger:
        rake requires Ruby version >= 2.2.

[root@puppetmaster bin]# yum update ruby
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
No Packages marked for Update

[root@puppetmaster bin]# yum upgrade ruby
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Upgrade Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
No Packages marked for Update



[root@puppetmaster bin]# ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]

[root@puppetmaster bin]# yum install ruby
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.cc.columbia.edu
 * extras: mirror.cc.columbia.edu
 * updates: mirror.cc.columbia.edu
Package ruby-1.8.7.374-5.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Comment: You need a newer version of Ruby, which is not available in your linux distribution repositories. You might want to take a look at [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [rvm](https://rvm.io/) to install newer version of Ruby.

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7 reached end-of-life about [seven years ago](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/). Seems like your distribution in extremely outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use rbenv for managing ruby

First install dependencies for rbenv and Ruby

```
   $ sudo yum install -y git-core zlib zlib-devel gcc-c++ patch readline readline-devel libyaml-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel make bzip2 autoconf automake libtool bison curl sqlite-devel
```

After install rbenv

```
    cd ~
    git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
    echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
    echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
    git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
    echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
    source ~/.bash_profile
```

Pick updated ruby version to use

```
rbenv install -l
```

Install ruby version

```
rbenv install -v $RUBY_VERSION
rbenv rehash
```

Set for global use

```
rbenv global $RUBY_VERSION
```

reference for full instructions 
[Install Ruby on Rails with Rbenv on CentOS 7](https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-centos-7)